# BindingList with my class populating a ComboBox using a property of it?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, combobox, bindinglist

I have a BindingList with my class where I would like to populate a ComboBox using a property of it so when my list changes the ComboBox would change as well.

```
public class UserAccess
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Access;
    }
    public int AccessId { get; set; }
    public string Access { get; set; }
    public List<string> Command = new List<string>();

    public bool HasCommand(string cmd)
    {
        return this.Command.Any(x => x == cmd);
    }
}

public BindingList<UserAccess> accessList = new BindingList<UserAccess>();
```

On my form load I assign it to the ComboBox:

```
myComboBox.DataSource = accessList;
```

I want to populate the box with Access or with the AccessId as value and Access as the printed name.

Problem is that it will print only the last item of the list to the combobox what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DisplayMember` to specify what field to use for display in the `ComboBox`.
Make `accessList` `readonly` to guarantee that you never recreate a new instance of the list. If you don't make it `readonly`, this may introduce a subtle bug, if you don't reassign `DataSource` whenever you recereate `accessList`.

```
private readonly BindingList<UserAccess> accessList = new BindingList<UserAccess>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.ValueMember = "AccessId";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Access";
    comboBox1.DataSource = accessList;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    accessList.Add(new UserAccess { AccessId = 1, Access = "Test1" });
    accessList.Add(new UserAccess { AccessId = 2, Access = "Test2" });
}
```

If you need to be able to change items properties in accessList (like `accessList[0].Access = "Test3"`) and see the changes reflected in UI, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

For example:

```
public class UserAccess : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int AccessId { get; set; }

    private string access;

    public string Access
    {
        get
        {
            return access;
        }

        set
        {
            access = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Access");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works like a charm, was not aware of the problem not using readonly which was good to know. Is it also possible to create a first entry to the combobox as default assigned to -1 or 0 without adding it to the list ?

Comment: If you use DataSource you need to maintain default -1 as an extra item in your list.

Comment: so I still need to add it to the list items I can't somehow add it directly to the list before the datasource ? For instance I would like to make the first item a item named Select: which cannot be select to tell the person he must select an access so they won't just create an user with the default access.

Comment: This is exactly what you should do. Add line like `accessList.Add(new UserAccess { AccessId = -1, Access = "Empty" });` as one of the first lines in your constructor. Difficult to suggest the simplest way of doing this, as you don't show the code that populates `accessList`.
`

Comment: when I load my application it will get a JSON from my API and this JSON is deserialized into the list thus creating it. So I think I will just add at the begin of the JSON list that is pulled from the data base the access -1 Select.