# Datagridview combo box: the combobox cell shows the ValueMember instead of DisplayMember and "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code to set up the combobox in data grid view.

```
class Lookup { byte Id {get; set;} string Text {get; set;} }
List<Lookup> rs = GetData(...);
cb.DataSource = rs;
cb.DisplayMember = "Text";
cb.ValueMember = "Id";
cb.DataPropertyName = "LookupId"; // The column of data source of grid view is also byte
```

However, I keep get error of "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.". What could cause the issue? After the value is selected, the combobox cell shows the number (Id) instead of "Text"?

**Update:**

The issue is caused by wrong type defined in `LookUp`.

Comment: I've removed the meta-request in the question to close this, and have cast a close vote (typo or not reproducible).

Answer (score 1):

In class 'Lookup' override the ToString() function and return the value of the Text property. You will not need an explicit assignment of DisplayMember since you are using an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **BindingList** take a look to this example:

[BindingList with my class populating a ComboBox using a property of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164264/bindinglist-with-my-class-populating-a-combobox-using-a-property-of-it)